# How to press multiple buttons on a webpage without knowing the id or xpath with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate the logging in and unfollowing of people on the website Depop. I am having a bit of trouble clicking all of the 'unfollow' buttons. Each of the buttons have a different ID and Class and the only similarities between them is this HTML code:

```
<span> Following <span>
```

Is there any way to click every button with this HTMl code?

I have already tried finding the XPath of all the buttons but because there are so many of them, it would be difficult to find the XPath of every single button. I have also tried to find the class of the follow buttons but they are all different. There are no similarities in the css selectors.

I have tried doing something like this but to no success.

```
driver.get_attribute('<span> Following </span>').click()
```

For optimum results, the program would go through the page, unfollowing everyone that is currently being followed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic.

```
unfollows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space(.)='Following']")
for btn in unfollows:
    btn.click()
```

If you get staleElement exception with the above approach then you have to follow the following approach.

```
while len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space(.)='Following']"))>0:
    btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[normalize-space(.)='Following'])[1]")
    btn.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",btn)
```

Comment: I got this error. ```selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span>...</span> is not clickable at point (322, 275). Other element would receive the click: <div class="sc-bsbRJL bcwqFE">...</div>```

Comment: Any ideas on ways to try fix it?

Comment: ```selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span>...</span> is not clickable at point (322, 275). Other element would receive the click: <div class="sc-bsbRJL bcwqFE">...</div>``` still getting this :(

Comment: Have you tried with javascript option, last line? make sure to comment `btn.click()`

Comment: What should I replace location_once_scrolled_into_view with?

Comment: check the updated code, I removed the normal click code so your should be able to click on all unfollow buttons now.

Comment: I edited the typo in ```driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",btn)``` but now there is no errors but it does not click the buttons

Comment: ok, is there any button inside span? May be the span have the text but there should be a button or element to click.

Comment: Can you check if there are any events associated with the span?

Comment: Im not sure how to find the event. it only has a href of ```javascript:;```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm unable to join the discussion. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Do you see the page scrolling to the unfollow buttons when your script runnning?

Comment: No, it doesn't scroll or press unfollow

Comment: have you tried `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space(.)='Following']")))`?

Comment: it prints 13 to the cli